# Ionic background geolocation service plugin installation error

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation

I want to add this plgin to my ionic application: https://www.transistorsoft.com/shop/products/cordova-background-geolocation

I have installed this plugin via npm, removed/readded the android platform.
And now, when I want to build/run the application, the build fails with an error.

```
:app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug FAILED
40 actionable tasks: 40 executed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.
```

build log is available here: https://pastebin.com/ZrRh7i7m

What can you advice? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the google play service version and whether it has any conflict with the Supported Cordova version.
https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt/issues/694

Comment: I understand that there is some problem with versions. They are conflicting, but I don't get what exactly is conflicting, why, and how to resolve.

In my config.xml, the plugin is added this way:
    <plugin name="cordova-background-geolocation-lt" spec="^2.12.2">
        <variable name="LICENSE" value="YOUR_LICENSE_KEY" />
        <variable name="GOOGLE_API_VERSION" value="11.8.0" />
        <variable name="APPCOMPAT_VERSION" value="27.0.0" />
    </plugin>
but in auto-generated platforms/android/project.properties file: target=android-26, so android version mismatch

Comment: I have tried to increase that number in project.properties, or decrease the number in config.xml, but both ways failed.